# Updating Client DataSet after Insert/delete query on same data: connection is busy with other command

Tags: sql, delphi, dataset, sqlconnection

I'm writing a simple database editor as my first Delphi program.

I don't have any problems with Delphi, only with the connection through the database.

I load the data in the datagrid with a `-> sqlConnection -> sqlDataSet -> sqlDataprovider -> Clientdataset -> Datasource`

I insert/delete records with a separate connection + `SqlQuery` for each.

I change the records with DBEdit

The problems occur when after I insert/delete a record, and I make a change to a record, and want to update the changes, I get the following error

> *Connection is busy for results from another command.*

Code:

```
procedure TDatabaseApp.bNieuwClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

//Waardes invullen in de query statement!

SQLInsert.ParamByName('naam').asString := txtNaam2.Text;
SQLInsert.ParamByName('brouwernr').asString := txtBrouwerNR.Text;
SQLInsert.ParamByName('soortnr').asString := TXTSoortNR.Text;
SQLInsert.ParamByName('alcohol').asString := TxtAlcohol.Text;

//query
SQLInsert.ExecSQL();
SQLInsert.Close();

//Reload datagrid after record has been inserted!
Refresh();

end;
```

Refresh code

```
procedure   TDatabaseApp.Refresh();
begin

//After a insert/delete query i call this statement, and changes made with the DBEdit are cancelled = temp solution.
  ClientDataSet1.CancelUpdates();  

  SQLDataSet1.Open();
  ClientDataSet1.Open();
  SQLDataSet1.Refresh();
  ClientDataSet1.Refresh();
end;
```

Comment: If by any chance the actual error is instead *"Connection is busy with results for another command*", the error is thrown from the database side..

Comment: Thnx, i'm changing the way the programs work, by inserting / removing records through the clientdataset. But i'm still wondering what actually causes the error!

Comment: It was also my impression about what to do after browsing [this thread](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=49746).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your ClientDataSet is linked to your DataSetProvider and your DataSetProvider is linked to your SQLDataSet you should NEVER manipulate the SQLDataSet directly, but instead do all operations using the ClientDataSet.

So, you will have:

```
procedure TDatabaseApp.Refresh();
begin
    //ClientDataSet1.CancelUpdates();  //will raise an error depends on the CDS state
    ClientDataSet1.Close;  
    ClientDataSet1.Open();

    //SQLDataSet1.Open(); //not necessary, as you already open the CDS
    //SQLDataSet1.Refresh(); //not necessary, as you already open the CDS
    //ClientDataSet1.Refresh(); //not necessary, as you already open the CDS
end;
```

But i would suggest you to also use the CDS for inserts, dispensing the use of the "SQLInsert" object. This way the things will become much simpler.